# Specific heat of a vortex lattice in a d-wave superconductor

Tags: resource-recommendations, superconductivity

I am looking for a reference that discusses the thermodynamic properties of Abrikosov lattices in d-wave superconductors, especially the discussion to calculate the specific heat of vortex lattice in the limit where they are rigid enough to maintain the lattice structure.